# How to evaluate spring ApplicationArguments before application context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to make use of `ApplicationArguments` for evaluation of var args:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
            ApplicationArguments arguments = new DefaultApplicationArguments(args);
            System.out.println(arguments.containsOption("export"));
            System.out.println(arguments.getOptionValues("export").equals("csv"));
        }

        //...
}
```

Problem: when running with `--export=true` as vararg, the `ApplicationArguments` never evaluates to true. Why?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I get output `true` and `false` when running `java MyClass --export=true`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I was using the wrong command. This works:

`java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev my.jar --export=csv`